# What controller structure is best for a SPA shop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

My team and I have developed an online store that is basically just one big SPA. The page basically lists every single product there is, which is usually between 100-300 articles.

The shop is right now based on one single controller, `StoreCtrl`, (and a few smaller controllers for modals). Every article has some functions that it uses from StoreCtrl (like add to cart and modify article). Now my question is, would we be better of by splitting up our StoreCtrl into many smaller controllers? We were thinking that there would be one controller for the cart, one for every article and one controller for the checkout area. Would this be a bad idea, as it would create between 100-300 ArticleCtrl instances? We are primarily worried about getting bad performance here. The alternative would be to create a controller, ArticlesCtrl, that hosts all of the articles.

What would you do?

Comment: Without some actual code it's difficult to judge. It's a good thing to break up the main controller into separate functions. However you can still set a click event on the whole page which calls upon a separate function when the user clicks on the cart or on a article.

Comment: Have you considered using services for your common functionality? For example, a cart service could manage the contents of the cart, which seems like a cleaner solution than using a controller (which is a UI entity). I'm confused on the 300 controllers point - do you mean an ngRepeat creating 300 scopes (which is fine), or something else?